# What makes a perfect landing page?

Tags: wireframe, landing-page

I would like to get advice on my landing page. My website provides mentorship services to professionals and entrepreneurs

I currently have the following sections:

- Header with a call to action
- Social Proof (Company logos where experts worked at)
- Images of 4 mentors on our platform with their titles
- How it works
- What we can help you with?
- Why Choose us
- Testimonials
- A call to action

Here's the wireframe - https://gomockingbird.com/projects/u99vg01

Can someone please give me some feedback on what I should include/remove?

Comment: Hi Chris, questions about reviews of a specific site are off-topic for this forum as it provides little value to everyone else. Maybe you can focus your question on one problem that is more applicable to all ux designers.

Comment: Hi Nash, I think is a page structure review, not a site review. While a little unprecise, I guess is an on-topic question.

Comment: I vote to close this because it's a Site Review and the link is dead

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this question is, that there are no vision or goals defined. You think, the UX only about the UI components and their order on the screen.

The most simple answer to your question is: "A good landing page converts". ... converting can mean: sells, gather leads, gather subscribers, etc.

A very good starting point to understand why is the vision or goal is the most important thing when designing a landing page and not the components itself, is the Measurement Plan by Google. You can read about it here: https://www.google-analytics.ie/blog/google-analytics-measurement-planning-guide/

So, your focus should be on the goal, what you want to achieve with your landing page. Have more bookings for video calls? Build brand awareness?

--

About the wireframe: it has two, way different target-audiences. Business and career advices...and no info on the page that how differently you can help them. There is also no promise above the fold. Maybe below. The second component on the screen is where your experts worked at...it is not important. The most important thing, that WHAT WILL I GET / WHO I MAY BECOME / WHAT I CAN ACHIEVE when booking a mentor from you. The most important thing to know about the potential users is that they always want to be better selves. First, they need a promise and then a validation of your expertises that you are really classified.

Collect job stories and user stories and answer for those questions to provide value for your potential customers. Currently, 99% of your landing page design is about how expert you are, and there is a very little info about how good someone could become with your help.

Comment: Hi, do you have an example webpage I can take a look at?

Comment: There are plenty of good examples. Like https://www.notion.so It starts with a very clear message, promise, proposition. Yes, there is some social proof under the first CTA button, but it is probably for the audience from the US and handled properly as a small, secondary/tertiary content on the page. Below the fold, it continues with how you, as a user can be better at something (value proposition) if you choose to register. Under that, you can find the testimonials as more social proof. Always have a good value proposition. 

"Any man who must say I am the king is no true king" - GoT

Answer (score 1):

None of those make a good landing page, you've just listed components of a webpage. First, ask the question - what is the main goal for the landing page, is it to collect beta users then just provide necessary information for prospective users such as "features & benefits" and then a simple yet clear CTA to capture "users" like a simple form.

If the purpose is to provide information for them to take the next step then only provide introductory/welcome/high-level information and then direct them to a primary CTA.

Once you have the above clear in your head, then you can pick and chose the right components. In my opinion, the best landing pages are short and to the point (ideally only do one thing).

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'Testimonials' should be #2 in the list of landing page attributes. As an example, please see the second block on this site that I helped many years ago https://www.upoharbd.com/. Also, the testimonials should be 'fresh'. On this site, it displays multiple least testimonials and the latest total number of testimonials. Together, they enhance the perception of trustworthiness in the testimonials and the brand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are off to a very good start. You seem to have genuine interest in your users' needs. I would suggest doing user research by conducting some usability testing of your landing pages with the users. Find a few users of your site (about 5 usually) and ask them about their experience.

First ask them some simple questions about their experience with any type of website like yours, what they were hoping to get out of it, and what they used it for. Then ask them to walk you through a few key tasks while using your website. If you are unsure what these may be, ask them to walk you through how they completed the last few things they did the last time they visited your site or create some scenarios that they can use your site to accomplish these tasks. Be sure to ask if you could record or take notes. This will show you how your users interact with your site and what they may need to make the landing pages and overall flow of the website better.